# Como adiciono um novo user numa tabela PL/SQL usando uma função?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Comecei à pouco tempo a trabalhar com PL/SQL e uma das duvidas que tenho é em criar e declarar funções.
Mais especificamente nesta:

-Cria uma função que cria um novo user:

```
1: Usa uma sequence para dar ao User um novo ID
2: Passa o nome, morada, etc... como IN argumentos
3: Returna como OUT argumentos o ID criado e uma mensagem de erro O_ERROR_MESSAGE
4: A função retorna TRUE se o user é adicionado, se não retorna FALSE
5: Não te esqueças das excepções
6: Cria um bloco PL/SQL e testa a função criada
```

Para já escrevi estas linhas de código:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS (I_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
                                                I_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2,
                                                I_BIRTHDATE IN DATE,
                                                I_COUNTRY IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    O_ERROR_MESSAGE EXCEPTION;
    CURRENT_USER NUMBER;

BEGIN

DSB_NB_SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL;
SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) INTO CURRENT_USER
FROM DSB_NB_USERS;

WHILE CURRENT_USER != 0
LOOP
DSB_NB_SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL;
SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) INTO CURRENT_USER
FROM DSB_NB_USERS;
END LOOP;

INSERT INTO DSB_NB_USERS (USER_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, BIRTHDATE, COUNTRY_ID_FK) VALUES (CURRENT_USER, I_NAME, I_ADDRESS, TO_DATE('I_BIRTHDATE', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), I_COUNTRY);

RETURN CURRET_USER;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN O_ERROR_MESSAGE THEN 
    RETURN NULL;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;

DECLARE
    I_NEW_USER NUMBER;
BEGIN
    I_NEW_USER := DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS(I_NAME => 'Arnaldo Amaral',
                                    I_ADDRESS => 'Rua da Agra',
                                    I_BIRTHDATE => '03/05/1959',
                                    I_COUNTRY => 'PT');                                 
END;
```

Estou muito longe da verdade? Eu sei que ainda falta adicionar algumas coisas.
Obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS (I_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
                                                I_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2,
                                                I_BIRTHDATE IN DATE,
                                                I_COUNTRY IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    CURRENT_USER NUMBER;

BEGIN
CURRENT_USER := DSB_NB_SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');

INSERT INTO DSB_NB_USERS (USER_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, BIRTHDATE, COUNTRY_ID_FK) VALUES (CURRENT_USER, I_NAME, I_ADDRESS, TO_DATE(I_BIRTHDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), I_COUNTRY);
RETURN CURRENT_USER;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    RETURN -1;

END;

SET SERVEROUT ON
DECLARE
    I_NEW_USER NUMBER;
BEGIN
    I_NEW_USER := DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS(I_NAME => 'Arnaldo Amaral',
                                    I_ADDRESS => 'Rua da Agra',
                                    I_BIRTHDATE => '03/MAY/1959',
                                    I_COUNTRY => 'PT');       
                                    commit;


END;
/
```

Depois de algumas horas a perguntar a varias pessoas, esta foi a solução encontrada e testada.

Obrigado!